# Session lifetime in node.js with express and MongoDB

Tags: session, mongodb, node.js, express, lifetime

I am using node.js with the express framework. As a session store I am using MongoDB. How can I set the lifetime after which the session objects are removed from MongoDB. This is how I am doing the declaration:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({
                secret: "Stays my secret",
                store: new MongoStore({ db: 'myDB' })
                    }));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is a little vague but from what i can gather you wan't to set the expiration period for the session:

you can use [`maxAge`](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-session.html) like so:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    secret  : "Stays my secret",
    maxAge  : new Date(Date.now() + 3600000), //1 Hour
    expires : new Date(Date.now() + 3600000), //1 Hour
    store   : new MongoStore({ db: 'myDB' })
}));
```

`expires` value is required for new versions of express where as `maxAge` is for older versions, you should only need `expires` though.

Comment: Thank you. Is the timer for maxAge reset every time the session is used or does it count from session creation?

Comment: Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429557/whats-the-correct-way-to-use-maxage-with-express-js, it looks like your Date-using setting calls for an "expires" key, not "maxAge".

Comment: maxAge should be an *age* (e.g. a value in miliseconds) not a *time* in the future.

Comment: @UpTheCreek I believe the unit is seconds not milliseconds... can anyone confirm?

Comment: @RoberPitt, here what is the use of MongoStroe and how it will be removed form db after session timeout? can you please explain

Answer (score 1):

@RobertPitt edit your answer.
Cookie (session) object looks like:

```
{
 "cookie":"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},
 "your_var_1":"value 1",
 "your_var_2":"value 2",
 ...
}
```

Argument for `express.session` should look like this (it's in documentation):

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret  : "Stays my secret",
    cookie: {
        maxAge  : new Date(Date.now() + 3600000), //1 Hour
        expires : new Date(Date.now() + 3600000), //1 Hour
    },
    store   : new MongoStore({ db: 'myDB' })
}));
```

Moreover this:

```
maxAge  : new Date(Date.now() + 3600000), //1 Hour
```

will cause that **every cookie (here also session) will be expired automatically one hour after server start**