# What's the correct way to use maxAge with Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have seen several variations.  Suppose I wish my cookie to expire after one second.  Should I use

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'mysecret',  maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 1000)}));
```

or

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'mysecret',  maxAge: 1000}));
```

or

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'mysecret',  cookie: {maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 1000)}}));
```

or

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'mysecret',  cookie: {maxAge: 1000}}));
```

Also suppose I have set my cookie expiring correctly and it has expired. If the user does not restart their browser do they still retain the cookie information until they do so?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you'll be better off looking at the source directly.

For Express it uses connect middleware, and here's the code for session https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/session.js#L67

And theres more documentation at the connect site
http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html

So you can do

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'mysecret',  cookie: {expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000)}}));
```

or

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'mysecret',  cookie: {maxAge: 1000}}));
```

Comment: i think in the first method the way you use "expires" option is not correct ! because the middle ware configuration here will be evaluated only one time  and all users will have the same expiry date.

Comment: The [link for the source code](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/8e57b21bef0d53010c4d37f4beee3f0341f3eaa6/session/cookie.js) has changed.